A confusion on a few parameters of two blocks connected with a spring
Let's say I have two blocks of mass $m_1$ and  $m_2$ and I connect it with a spring constant of $k$. I compress it to a distance $x_0$ and release. I now wish to find the maximum  speed.
Now since spring force is internal, the COM of the two blocks should remain in the same place they were any further displacement of the blocks should have some relation.
Namely $m_1x_1$=$m_2x_2$ where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the maximum displacements of the blocks. Is it correct to say that $x_1$+$x_2$ = $x_0$. Now, is the spring potential energy of the block $m_1$ is $\frac{1}{2}kx_1^2$ and that of the other block $\frac{1}{2}kx_2^2$?
And that at the maximum extension, the kinetic enrgy is zero. so $\frac{1}{2}kx_2^2$ +$\frac{1}{2}kx_1^2$ =$\frac{1}{2}kx_0^2$, so yielding $x_1^2$+$x_2^2$=$x_0^2$. Now I do know that the first equan is 101% correct but I do not know of the 2 other equations which one is correct as they would yield different situations.

This is very confusing.  Are you assigning individual displacements for each mass in compressing the spring?

yes. I am doing that

There was a similar question asked some time ago that made the mistake of assuming (x1 + x2)^2 = x1^2 + x2^2.  Not sure, but you may be making the same error here.


Is it correct to say that $x_1$+$x_2$ = $x_0$.

Yes.

Now, is the spring potential energy of the block $m_1$ is $\frac{1}{2}kx_1^2$ and that of the other block $\frac{1}{2}kx_2^2$?

No. There is not a separate PE for each block. The PE of the system is $PE=\frac{1}{2}k x_0^2$ Since $x_0=x_1+x_2$ we can expand this to $PE=\frac{1}{2} k x_1^2 + \frac{1}{2} k x_2^2 + k x_1 x_2$

so $\frac{1}{2}kx_2^2$ +$\frac{1}{2}kx_1^2$ =$\frac{1}{2}kx_0^2$, so yielding $x_1^2$+$x_2^2$=$x_0^2$.

This is incorrect. It is missing the $kx_1 x_2$ term.

Hmm so what is that $kx_1x_2$ term?

I mean I kinda thought of it as both block vibrating about the centre of mass, so each block may have its own kinetic and potential energy analagous to a block connected to a spring connected to a wall.

The $kx_1 x_2$ term is just from the expansion of $\frac{1}{2}k x_0^2 = \frac{1}{2}k(x_1+x_2)^2$. It is just algebra

hmm so it does'nt have any physical significance?

It has the physical significance is that it is part of the total energy of the system that cannot be ignored. When you express the energy in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$ you have to include that

@Psychic456 If I understand your question correctly, the physical significance of the cross term is that increasing the extension from $x_1$ to $x_1+x_2$ is not the same as extending it from $0$ to $x_2$. The term captures the additional energy needed to do so.

Another way to think about it is that it represents the fact that the force in the spring is increasing faster than what you would expect from $x_1$ and $x_2$ separately
